# Powershell while not working

Tags: powershell, loops, while-loop

can anybody tell what is wrong with this, or if it could be done in another way , it just never stop.

```
$IDs = Get-CMOperatingSystemImage | Where-Object {($_.name -like "*Windows Server*") } 

        foreach ($ID in $IDs ) {

                 while (((Get-CimInstance –NameSpace "root\SMS\site_$($SiteCode)" –Class SMS_DistributionDPStatus -ComputerName $SiteServer).MessageID -ne '2330') -and 
                 ((Get-CimInstance –NameSpace "root\SMS\site_$($SiteCode)" –Class SMS_DistributionDPStatus -ComputerName $SiteServer).PackageID -eq $ID.PackageID)){


                 Write-Output "Waiting for newly imported Operating Systems to be distributed to DP..."
                 Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
                 } 

                 Write-Output "successfully distributed to DP" 

        }
```

Comment: Exactly what is your script *supposed* to do?  All we can see is what it actually does, not what you want it to do.  Or are you saying the CIM values are actually changing and the loop isn't noticing?

Comment: Yes correct, i have  `Start-CMContentDistribution'`, above  CIM values are changing, the loop just continues to output _Waiting for newly imported..._